# Run a command on Windows host after the VirtualBox guest it hosts has powered up

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

There are several ways of running commands on the hosted ("guest") machine from the outside "host" machine.

What I'm looking for is more **the opposite** - after I power up the virtual machine, I need to, say, open a Web page on the server running inside the VM, with the browser running outside the VM.

It's not actually that I want to run the command *from the guest* - it would actually be even better if the host did it all, power up the VM and run the command, with the guest none the wiser.

Since it is the host that starts the guest, I'd have thought that it would be supplied of some post-run hook. Granted, the host can know when the VM has powered on, but cannot know *when it finished booting* (although, with VirtualBox Tool addition maybe...?).

I thought that there was a way to exploit the VM communication protocol to do this, of course with the necessary defenses - there may be a good reason for running something in a VM and not let the genie out of the bottle - but it seems this feature isn't available at all.

The closest I've been able to come is a very roundabout way:

1. install WinSSHd (SSH for Windows) on the host machine, since I've not been able to get [PowerShell remoting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/running-remote-commands) to run from the Linux guest VM
2. hook the power up script on the guest machine
3. generate a SSH key on the guest and install it as trusted on the host
4. run a SSH command (or more than one) from the guest to the host
5. profit.

But installing the SSH daemon on Windows isn't really something I feel comfortable with, so... *is there another way*?

Comment: You could write a script that pings the VM and when it's up, start the web page; it could potentially ping but that will just tell you when the network stack is active, if it's a web page, it could telnet to port 80. A successful connect would mean it's active, disconnect the telnet and spawn the web page ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox does not have a "run this host program" command that can be executed from the guest. But Virtualbox Guest Additions have "guestproperties": a low-bandwidth text-string transfer mechanism between host and guest, which can be used with scripts to run a host program when the guest script says to.

This command is run on the host:

```
"Vboxmanage.exe guestproperty get|set /customnameclass/custompropertyname"
```

and this in the guest:

```
"Vboxcontrol.exe guestproperty get|set /customnameclass/custompropertyname"
```

A host script can set a guestproperty using the Vboxmanage command to a 'changed' value then get the guestproperty in a loop, waiting for the value to change back. When the value changes back, the script can continue to run other desired commands.

On the guest, another script can wait for a desired service to be available then set the guestproperty using the VboxControl command to the value the host script is waiting for. The script could loop, continuing to set the guestproperty while the service exists and not setting the guestproperty when the service is off. Thus the host can know when the guest's service is present and usable.

`/customnameclass` and `/custompropertyname` are any names you wish to use. Multiple channels of communication can be set up using different class and property names.

If you don't want or can't use Guest Additions, a similar concept can be used with flag files in a shared folder. Guest script creates the flag file (a simple text file with a known name) in the shared folder; the host script looks for the flag file and runs the desired program.

If you have Windows for both host and guest you can use Microsoft Sysinternals' "PsExec", which runs commands between networked Microsoft PCs without requiring a polling script on the host PC.